Gulpjs wait for async function before continue
I cut gulpfile.js into several files. My purpose is to share the data with various tasks. And I use windows system, gulp 5 and "type": "module" config.
The file structure is given below:
gulpfile.js
tasks/clean.js
tasks/deploy_data.js
data/path.js
data/other.js

gulpfile.js
import gulp from 'gulp';
import clean from './tasks/clean.js';
import deploy_data from './data/deploy_data.js';

global.data = {}; // share data with all tasks.

function deploy_at_start() {
  gulp.series(deploy_data);
}

deploy_at_start(); // I hope that deploy_data will be executed before any task I debug, because each task needs to use the contents of data.

console.log(data); // {} Blank, obviously deploy_data has not been completed yet, I want the code below to be executed only after it completes.

export {
  clean,
  // alot of other tasks
};

./tasks/clean.js
function clean(cb) {
  console.log(data.path.src); // I need to get some information from data, such as the path I want to delete.
  cb();
}

export default clean;

The point is this
data/path.js
const path = {
  src: './folder/*',
};

export default path;

tasks/deploy_data.js
import path from 'node:path';
import { pathToFileURL } from 'node:url';

async function deploy_data(cb) {
  const dir = path.join(process.cwd(), 'data');
  const files = fs
.readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true }).filter((item) => item.isFile())
.map((item) => item.name); // I have a lot of data files, so this is the easier way to get all the data

  for (const file of files) {
    data[path.parse(file).name] = (await import(pathToFileURL(path.join(dir, file)).href)).default;
  }

  cb();
}

export default deploy_data;

When I execute gulp clean, I can't get the data.path information. I think it may be because deploy_data is async and something went wrong.
From the terminal, I can see that deploy_data completes its work after clean is completed, which is why data is empty.
I understand that I can use gulp.series to execute deploy_data before clean, but I have a huge amount of data. I think I can achieve the goal by executing deploy_data once at the beginning of gulpfile.js similar to the current method.
In the above case, is there a way for me to execute deploy_data before executing any gulp task (the task that has been exported) and wait for it to complete before executing other code?

Just add a top-level await:
await deploy_at_start();

and don't forget to return from deploy_at_start so await would wait gulp.series() to finish:
function deploy_at_start() {
  return gulp.series(deploy_data);
}


I tried it before asking the question, but it was unsuccessful and only returned {}. Finally, I found that it was successful as long as cb() in deploy_data was changed to cb. Your answer is correct, but there was something wrong with my code. This Very strange, do you know the reason? Why does cb affect the results?

@aboutjquery i've added some extra info to the answer

I tested the new method you provided but it didn't work, but your previous answer worked. top level await deploy_data can generate data before I execute gulp clean, but I want to ask a little more, if I want to maintain const deploy_at_start = gulp.series (deploy_data, // other deploy task); format because there will be more tasks in the future that need to be run before other tasks are executed...

If I want to run any task, such as gulp clean, deploy_at_start() will generate data first. Now I have a problem For example, when executing gulp clean, the sequence is Starting 'deploy_data', Starting 'clean', Finished 'clean' Finished 'deploy_data. What I expected was to finish depoy_data first and then start cleaning. I tried for two days and couldn't find the reason. , or I should open a new topic.
